# Network manager not connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

The issue I'm facing in Ubuntu 20.04 is that on my network panel it shows that my laptop is connected to a wired network, but there isn't any wired cable connected. With that being said, connecting to a Wi-Fi network does connect, but I can't use the internet.

This is the second time it happened. The first time I had to reinstall Ubuntu. My best guess about the cause is that it's ProtonVPN, but I don't know that for sure. I followed every step listed on the official [ProtonVPN website](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-openvpn/).

I basically don't want to connect to a VPN because it won't connect either way. I want to be able to use the internet normally like I would after a fresh Linux install, but the Ethernet symbol that shows on my network panel is preventing me from connecting to the internet.

Comment: Maybe my question is not constructed correctly. But what I'm saying is that after using Proton VPN for a couple of days, my network gets corrupted. It shows a wired connection symbol while there isn't any. And that prevents any type of connection to the internet. (VPN is not connected at this point)

Comment: Your question is constructed correctly. I don't think your network is corrupted. It's probably just not configured correctly to be compatible with ProtonVPN.

Comment: Ok. Could you maybe provide the configurations because I followed every step listen on their website.

Comment: Yes I did. Followed every step till the part where it shows how to use or connect to the VPN.   That's why it was working perfectly for a couple of days. Then this issue happens. My guess that It could be a VPN isn't exactly an accurate guess since I'm just a moderate Linux user. There could be other causes to this issue

Comment: Here are the configurations: Log into your ProtonVPN dashboard at [account.protonvpn.com](https://account.protonvpn.com/login).   Select Downloads on in the left navigation bar.
    Find the OpenVPN configuration files section and chose: Platform: Linux, Protocol: UDP (recommended. TCP uses port 443. Use it if you experience slow VPN speeds or your VPN connection is dropped)

Comment: Configuration files are the servers which the VPN will connect to right? If I'm not mistaken. But I basically don't want to connect to a VPN.  Because it won't connect either way. I want to be able to use the internet normally like I would after a fresh Linux install. But the Ethernet symbol that shows on my network panel is preventing the internet connection.

Comment: This sounds like DNS problem, which can happen if a VPN client software messes up. Have you tried purging the VPN client software?

Comment: @user68186 I encountered a similar problem. I didn't purge the software, however I manually configured the DNS settings among other things that I did to configure the network settings manually and it solved the problem.